# Encoding byte[] to string

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I am trying to send bytes over Bluetooth on Tizen.NET, however the interface only allows me to send strings instead of byte arrays. So what I need to do now is :

Sender : byte array -> string -> Some Weird Tizen Logic

Receiver : read stream to uint8

Now I am struggling with finding out what encoding I need in order to receive the bytes I want on the other end.

I tried several things but I am not able to find out what is causing this. I figured I probably need Windows-1252 encoding, and up to 0x7F I am receiving the correct correspoinding uint8 on the receiver side. But all the others are ending up in weird symbols, e.g. 0xFE results in Ã¾

I found this table : https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html
which pretty much lists exactly the Actual/Expected characters that occur to me, but I nowhere found a way to solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: UTF and  Windows encodings have to do with converting *strings* to bytes, not the other way round. You *can't* convert random bytes to Unicode strings - some byte sequences are invalid. What does the other device expect? What kind of string, what kind of format? What do those bytes contain anyway, and why do you expect the device to be able to understand that data, if it can only receive strings?

Comment: A common way to convert byte arrays to strings is to use Base64 encoding. You can use [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8). The receiver has to know about this though.

Comment: The other device expects bytes, but Tizen does not allow me to send them. So all I can influence is the way I convert my bytes to a string, that then gets converted back to a byte before sending, to which I have no insight.

Comment: I have bytes in the range of 0 and 254 that I want to send, and I am expecting the same range of bytes on the other side.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Bluetooth isn't a dumb port, is uses device profiles with specific protocols. What are you trying to do, what does your code look like? *No* library would send strings when the device expects audio.

Comment: I am communicating ove SPP with the device if that answers your question. Otherwise I don't understand it

Comment: Since the byte `0xFE` results in `Ã¾`, it is obvious that UTF-8 encoding is used to convert the string to bytes (and not Windows-1252). Not every byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 encoded string; many are invalid. This implies that it is impossible to generate all bytes sequences from string that will be UTF-8 encoded. Therefore, you cannot achieve what you want with the given API (if the encoding cannot be changed).

Comment: Hm ok that is sad to hear, so I need to wait for Tizen to implement a byte based interface...

Comment: Can I know which C# BT API you are using to send bytes? And on which tizen device? (For to checking .Net API version)

Comment: @DoHyunPyun TizenFX it is, on a Galaxy Watch https://github.com/Samsung/TizenFX/blob/96c3309bf93b2a828053654e75e933b65500b343/src/Tizen.Network.Bluetooth/Tizen.Network.Bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you said is SendData(string), new API sending byte will be introduced in next .NET API version.
Please refer this issue page.
https://github.com/Samsung/TizenFX/issues/1218

Thank you